# Get count of siblings in subdocument with mongodb aggregate query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document collection with a subdocument of tags.

```
{
    title:"my title",
    slug:"my-title",
    tags:[
        {tagname:'tag1', id:1},
        {tagname:'tag2', id:2},
        {tagname:'tag3', id:3}]
}
{
    title:"my title2",
    slug:"my-title2",
    tags:[
        {tagname:'tag1', id:1},
        {tagname:'tag2', id:2}]
}
{
    title:"my title3",
    slug:"my-title3",
    tags:[
        {tagname:'tag1', id:1},
        {tagname:'tag3', id:3}]
}
{
    title:"my title4",
    slug:"my-title4",
    tags:[
        {tagname:'tag1', id:1},
        {tagname:'tag2', id:2},
        {tagname:'tag3', id:3}]
}
```

[...]

Getting a count of every tag is quite simple with an $unwind + group count aggregate

However, I would like to find a count of which tags are found together, or more precisely, which sibling shows up most often beside one another, ordered by count.  I have not found an example nor can I figure out how to do this without multiple queries.

Ideally the end result would be:

```
{'tag1':{
    'tag2':3, // tag1 and tag2 were found in a document together 3 times
    'tag3':3, // tag1 and tag3 were found in a document together 3 times
    [...]}}

{'tag2':{
    'tag1':3, // tag2 and tag1 were found in a document together 3 times
    'tag3':2, // tag2 and tag3 were found in a document together 2 times
    [...]}}

{'tag3':{
    'tag1':3, // tag3 and tag1 were found in a document together 3 times
    'tag2':2, // tag3 and tag2 were found in a document together 2 times
    [...]}}

[...]
```

Comment: I think you meant `"tags": [ {} ]` because that would be array syntax as compared to what you have typed, which would actually not be a valid document structure. You cannot create arbitrary "key names" with the aggregation framework. It also does not seem likely as a possibility to get your desired result (or close to it), but I'm really only guessing because your question lacks a clear sample that could possibly produce a clear expected result. See: [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is just simplified offhand, the original document is quite large the the subdocument is also very large.

Comment: See you corrected the array notation. Not asking you to submit the whole thing, just a sample and a result that could actually be obtained ( desired ) from the data in that sample. It makes your question a lot clearer than it currently is.

Comment: Is it clear enough yet or do you require additional clarifications.

Comment: "How would we get the result you are showing you expect based on the single document data sample you provide?" We cannot. So I am asking you to provide enough documents that would be able to produce the sample output you expect.

Answer (score 2):

As stated earlier it just simply is not possible to have the aggregation framework generate arbitrary key names from data. It's also not possible to do this kind of analysis in a single query.

But there is a general approach to doing this over your whole collection for an undetermined number of tag names. Essentially you are going to need to get a distinct list of the "tags" and process another query for each distinct value to get the "siblings" to that tag and the counts.

In general:

```js
// Get a the unique tags
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$tags.tagname"
    }}
]).forEach(function(tag) {
    var tagDoc = { };
    tagDoc[tag._id] = {};

    // Get the siblings count for that tag
    db.collection.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "tags.tagname": tag._id } },
        { "$unwind": "$tags" },
        { "$match": { "tags.tagname": { "$ne": tag._id } } },
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$tags.tagname",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }}
    ]).forEach(function(sibling) {
          // Set the value in the master document
          tagDoc[tag._id][sibling._id] = sibling.count;   
    });
    // Just emitting for example purposes in some way
    printjson(tagDoc);
});
```

The aggregation framework can return a cursor in releases since MongoDB 2.6, so even with a large number of tags this can work in an efficient way.

So that's the way you would handle this, but there really is no way to have this happen in a single query. For a shorter run time you might look at frameworks that allow many queries to be run in parallel either combining the results or emitting to a stream.

Comment: This is similar to my previous approach which was a distinct query followed by an unwind and group.  Is there no way to do it in a single aggregate?

Comment: @tweak2 No it would not be possible to do in a single pass for the reasons already described in the answer here. Also noted is the difference that a `.distinct()` command returns an array and not a cursor, so there are limitations on the size of results you can obtain. Working with a cursor and output streams removes the limitation. Also `.distanct()` cannot "filter" the array content as is required for the actual "siblings".